# Remove volley cache

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I want to clear the cache, but nothing seems to work, I tried with `getCache().clear` or `getCache.remove(url)`, also deleting before and after the  request, but nothing changes.

Here is my code:

```
requestQueue.getCache().clear();
requestQueue.getCache().remove(Links.ENTERPRISE_ADD + email);

requestQueue.add(
        new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                Links.ENTERPRISE_EMAIL_EXISTS + email,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (!emailExists(response)) {
                            try {
                                addToDatabase();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                clearFields();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.email_in_use, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Snackbar.make(layout, R.string.error_connecting_server, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("Error check email", error.toString());
                        clearFields();
                    }
                }
        )
);
```

Comment: Check this [Reference of already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755109/disable-or-remove-cache-in-networkimageview-volley).
This may help you :-)

Comment: I think thats the duplicate question[another link may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584210/how-to-refresh-volley-caching). :-)